# BizTalk Message Context Properties 'MessageTracking.AdapterReceiveCompleteTime'

Tags: biztalk

I have a running code in production environment which is extracting `MessageTracking.AdapterReceiveCompleteTime` from the message context and assigning it to a variable.

Until yesterday it was working fine but I don't know what has happened and now I cannot see this property in the message context. Does anyone have an idea what could cause this BizTalk behavior.

```
OriginalMessage.ReceiveTime = GetInvoiceResponseMsg(MessageTracking.AdapterReceiveCompleteTime);
```

Comment: Was there any other change done in production, e.g. server patching etc?